# How to get and store accessToken from passport.js using Google-OAUTH2 strategy in Node.js?

Tags: express, jwt, passport.js, session-cookies, passport-google-oauth

I have my passport.js setup and all my callbacks work. In the function where I have access to the accessToken I'm trying to store that in a cookie. However, I noticed it comes out as an encoded value I'm not sure how to decode and thus am not able to store to use later.

**My main goal is just to get that decoded accessToken, save it in a cookie on my backend, so that I can use it later for more API calls.**

I'm either not sure how to decode the accessToken it gives me, or I'm misunderstanding how this passport OAUTH process works. Thank you in advance!

**Passport.js file: **

```
const passport = require("passport");
require("dotenv").config();
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {//HERE is the issue I think

            //this fires righgt before my actual callback function at "/auth/google/callback"
            //when the second passport.authenticate middleware is called
            console.log(accessToken); //store token here
            res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, maxAge: 3600000 });
            done(null, profile);
        }
    )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
```

**My Auth endpoints file:**

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
var passport = require("passport");
//const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth").OAuth2Strategy;

// Creating express Router
const router = express.Router();

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "our-google-client-id";
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = "our-google-client-secret";

router.get("/success", (req, res) => res.send("UWU"));
router.get("/error", (req, res) => res.send("error logging in"));

router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] })); //this navigates to the consent screen to
//get code from user profile

//Call passport.authenticate again(now with code after consent screen) and obtain profile data(and accessToken)
router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        successRedirect: "/auth/success",
        failureRedirect: "/auth/error",
    })
);

module.exports = router;
```

**Here is my index.js file(starting point of code):**

```
const express = require("express"); //import express
const session = require("express-session");
const app = express(); //express server
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const PORT = 8080;
const passportSetup = require("./passport");
const passport = require("passport");

const cors = require("cors"); //install cors
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "cookieSecret",
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

const loginroute = require("./routes/auth"); //import routing from routes/login
const youtubeRoutes = require("./routes/youtube")(io);
```